# Byte array unioned with a struct (byte aligment)

Tags: c, struct, unions, memory-alignment, avr-gcc

I would like to combine a struct and a byte array in a union. The compiler is gcc.

Is the following considered good/save code for a 32bit embedded controller (AVR)?
Do I have to worry about the byte aligment?

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int8_t S8;

typedef union {
    struct {
        S8 a;
        S8 b;
        S8 c;
        S8 d;
        S8 e;
    };
    S8 array[5];
} s_t;
```

**Initialization:**

```
s_t s = {.array = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
```

**Access:**

```
s.a = 50;
s.c = 42;
```

Comment: Compiler could haave been handling that auto. Endianness is important.

Comment: you should use the `stdint.h` data type `uint8_t` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're showing is fine, but you should be worried if you ever use an array of `s_t` as there might be padding at the end.

You can tell GCC to "pack" the struct using the extension [`__attribute__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) syntax. Add `__attribute__((packed))` before the final `;`.

Comment: I don't think that padding at the end of the struct is a problem, in real life (even though the C standard doesn't guarantee it). The alignment of the struct is inherited from it's members, as they all are 8 bit entities, none of them will raise the alignment of the structure. A *packed* structure, on the other hand, is something that I would wholeheartedly discourage you from using! It's not part of the C standard and people really don't know what the consequences are of using it.

Comment: As I see it, *packed* structures/unions are the *only* way to make sure a structure or union is layed out in memory in a predictable way. Depending on the target architecture the compiler may, for example, well choose to assign each 1-byte *variable* to its own 4-byte word in memory, which just silently breaks the array access to these variables.